# Images on the sides of a centered text

Tags: graphics, horizontal-alignment, text

On top of my titlepage I have a centered title and I have to put a logo both on the left and the right side of the text (similar to what you see in the picture below). I think I can do this using tables or minipages but I cannot find an easy implementation. Can you help me?[image: Made in libreoffice]

Comment: How do you currently construct your title page or the text you show in the picture? From there one could be able to help you place the images.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{cXc}
\raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics{logo1}}& Some more or less long title 
&\raisebox{-0.5\height}{\includegraphics{logo2}}
\end{tabularx}
```

Maybe also change the definition of the `X` column type in your preamble:

```
\renewcommand{\tabularxcolumn}[1]{m{#1}}
```